# In grails, how do I get a reference to all current sessions?

Tags: session, grails, controller, httpsession

I'd like to list all current sessions in an Admin Controller in grails. What's the easiest way to get a reference to e.g. a Collection of sessions from the controller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature (disabled by default but easily enabled by setting `grails.plugins.appinfo.useContextListener = true` in Config.groovy) of the App-Info plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/app-info

Comment: @Burt Excellent Plugin, that I never knew about... will definitely investigate today

Comment: Looks very promising! However I'm getting the following error when trying to run after install: "Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies: [appInfo]
- Plugin: appInfo, Dependencies: [dynamicController, googleVisualization, jquery]" I found some discussions on that but none solved my problem. The stated plugins are all installed and listed in application.xml, I deleted .ivy2 and re-installed but I still get the error... using STS 2.3.3.M2 with grails 1.3.4. Can you point me in some direction?

Comment: Are you already using one of the dynamicController, googleVisualization, or jquery plugins?

Comment: I installed all of them for your plug-in, however I'm only using the jquery plug-in in my project.

Comment: I reinstalled everything on Linux and got it working now. The plug-in is cool, but no sessions are listed in Info / Sessions, even when I log on with another user in another browser. What could be the reason for this? I'm using shiro security if it matters. I did NOT set grails.plugins.appinfo.useContextListener = false.

Comment: It's false by default - you need to set it to true.

Comment: Great, now it works - I thought I'd read the opposite somewhere... ;-) Thank you for the great plug-in! Now I can also use your grails.plugins.appinfo.ScopesInfoService to show the number of users "online" via scopesInfoService.getSessionsInfo().size()

Answer (score 2):

there is a "groovy" way to do this without a SessionListener, there are events generated that closures can be assigned to. You can capture successful sessions, in a map/list, and remove sessions from after logout or

[Registering Callback Closures](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/7%20Events.html#7.3%20Registering%20Callback%20Closures)

```
rails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   // handle InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent
}

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   // handle AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent
}

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   // handle AuthenticationSuccessEvent
}

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAuthenticationSwitchUserEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   // handle AuthenticationSwitchUserEvent
}

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAuthorizationEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   // handle AuthorizationEvent
}
```