# Is it possible to get a List of all active Sessions?

Tags: spring, servlets, grails, grails-2.0

When being in a Grails action I can access a HTTPSession with **session**.

Is it also possible to get a list of all active sessions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683231/in-grails-how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-all-current-sessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getSessionsInfo()` method of `ScopesInfoService` service of [Application Info](http://grails.org/plugin/app-info) plugin.

First install plugin(in BuildConfig)

```
compile ":app-info:1.0.2"{
        excludes 'jquery'
}
```

then make an entry in Config

```
grails.plugins.appinfo.useContextListener = true
```

finally inject service and use its `getSessionsInfo()` method

```
def scopesInfoService
...
scopesInfoService.getSessionsInfo()
```

to get the list of all active sessions.

Comment: when is do refresh-dependencies I get an errror because the plugin tries to install jquery 1.8.0 and I use 1.8.3. Do you have solution for that?

Comment: You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [jquery-1.8.3]. Do you want to update to [jquery-1.8.0]? [y,n] n..,.

Same asked my side, I reply no. And works for me.

Comment: I am using grails 2.2.0 version and app-info working fine. Not sure on grails 2.2.4, lets wait for the fix.

Comment: do you have any idea how to fix it, that jquery is not loaded in an old version?

Answer (score 4):

This is the answer to your question in comments:

I was able to get it work with 2.2.4, without any issue. Make sure you read this [blog](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1457) for compatibilities with grails 2+.

To exclude the jquery version use:

```
compile (":app-info:1.0.2" ){
            excludes 'jquery'
}
```

This way your are telling Grails not to use plugins' jquery but your app.

Comment: How can I get the getLastAccessedTime() from these sessions?